# update table fields objective-c

Tags: objective-c

File Data.m

```
-(void)update:(NSMutableDictionary *)materia {



  if (sqlite3_open([pathDB UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // query per l'inserimento di una nuova materia
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE libretto SET Nome='%@',Voto='%@',CFU='%@' WHERE CFU='6'",[materia objectForKey:@"Nome" ],[materia objectForKey:@"Voto"],[materia objectForKey:@"CFU"]];

        const char *sql = [query UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement;
        // eseguiamo la query
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_step(insert_statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                // ricarichiamo la lista
                [self caricaValori];
            }

        }
        // chiudiamo il db
        sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

file viewcontroller.m

I added in file.m

```
-(IBAction)update:(id)sender {



    _nome=[[Data alloc]init];

    _cell=[[MasterViewController alloc]init];



        if(_cell.indexpath2.row==0 ) {

     if([fieldNome.text isEqualToString:_nome.nome]){


    // creiamo un dizionario con i valori
    NSMutableDictionary *materia = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:fieldNome.text, @"Nome", fieldCFU.text, @"CFU",fieldVoto.text,@"Voto", nil];



    //inseriamolo nel db
    [dataList update:materia];


    // torniamo alla lista
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


     }
    }




}
```

The problem that I only updates only the first field of the table.

If I add more names in the table I do not upgrade in any field

How can I fix?

Comment: Are you sure the values are being stored correctly in the dictionary?  Use a debugger to break on the update line and check its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You've hardcoded `CFU` in `WHERE` clause of your query to '6'.

Couple of advices:

1. Do not embed parameter values in your query. Absence of proper escaping will cause weird bugs for some values and will allow SQL injection attacks. Use `sqlite3_bind_*` functions instead.
2. Do not use sqlite directly unless you really know why you are doing this. CoreData is better for 99% of typical apps.

Comment: To change the contents of a table with the same name.

But after entering more than one name I do not update the data

Comment: I don't even know if you are trying to insert a new record or update an existing record.

Comment: @Francesco quick and dirty solution is to replace `WHERE CFU='6'` with `WHERE CFU='%@'` and adding another `[materia objectForKey:@"CFU"]` to the argument list. Everything I said earlier will still apply - this code should be rewritten entirely to rise the quality.

Comment: @Francesco try log and check your queries. What do you see?